# Google maps infowindow doesnt work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When the page has loaded all infowindow is open. Later the infowindow is closed I cant open again. Where is my mistake?

```
    function init() {
       var center = {lat: <?=$lat?>, lng: <?=$lng?>};
       var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 12,
          center: center
      });   
      <?php for($i=0; $i<5; $i++){ ?>
            var myLatLng = {lat:<?=$json[$i]['latitute']?>, lng:<?=$json[$i]['longitute']?>};                    
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatLng, 
                map: map
            });             
  var contentString = "<table'><tr>"+
    "<td><a href='<?=$json[$i]['image'];?></td>"+
    "</tr></table>";
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
    }); 
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   infowindow.open(map,this);
    });
  infowindow.close(map,marker);    
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
     map: map
   });
<?php } ?>
 }
```

Comment: Do you want that initial state, of all infowindows to be open?

Comment: I solved my problem thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're overwriting your variables. Your PHP loop uses the same name for every marker and infowindow. Perhaps add  after each identifier?

```
var marker<?= $i;?> = ...
var infowindow<?= $i;?> = ...
```

I basically did a manual test of your loop using 5 markers and infowindows with the repeated variables hardcoded in javascript. What happens for me, in that case, is EVERY marker opens just ONE of the infowindows. Which makes sense, since you're overwriting the marker variable and the event you're binding.

Regardless, the variable overwriting is an issue you'll have to deal with, as I'm certain that's not the behavior you're trying to achieve.